# JQuery slidedown() slideup() when radiobutton is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to Javascript, and can't seem to find the information I'm looking for.
I'm trying to make another div slide down when the "Yes" radio button is clicked, and slide back up when "No" is clicked. However, nothing is happening when I click either one. This is my current code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="field">
<label for="">Apprentice</label>
<div class="topRadio">
<input name="apprentice" group="apprentice" type="radio" value="Yes" onclick="dropbcitdown()">
<label for="">Yes</label>
<input name="apprentice" group="apprentice" type="radio" value="No" onclick="pickbcitup()">
<label for="">No</label>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="field slidingdiv" id="doyouattend">
<label for="">Do you attend BCIT?</label>
<div class="topRadio">
<input name="bcit" group="bcit" type="radio" value="Yes" onclick="droptransportationdown()">
<label for="">Yes</label>
<input name="bcit" group="bcit" type="radio" value="No" onclick="picktransportationup()">
<label for="">No</label>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class ="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="field slidingdiv" id="doyouneed">
<label for="">Do you need ground transportation to city hall?</label>
<div class="topRadio">
<input name="transportation" group="transportation" type="radio" value="Yes">
<label for="">Yes</label>
<input name="transportation" group="transportation" type="radio" value="No">
<label for="">No</label>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function bcitDown() {
    $("#doyouattend").slideDown("slow" function() {
        $(this).css({
        display: "inline";
        })
    })
}

function bcitUp() {
    $("#doyouattend").slideUp("slow" function() {
        $(this).css({
        display: "none";
        })
    })
}

function transportationDown() {
    $("#doyouneed").slideDown("slow" function() {
        $(this).css({
        display: "inline";
        })
    })
}

function transportationUp() {
    $("#doyouneed").slideUp("slow" function() {
        $(this).css({
        display: "none";
        })
    })
}
</script>
```

I have also tried doing it with the values of the radiobuttons, but I can't submit the for before they drop down. Unrelated, but the '' making a line break if anyone is wondering why that's happening. I have tried running this without that, and haven't had a different outcome.
If I am making a glaring syntax error, or this ends up being some obvious solution that I totally missed, I'm sorry. I just feel that I've tried everything.
NOTE: I have included JQuery.

Comment: There is so much wrong here. For starters, have you included jQuery? `$().slideDown` is a jQuery method; you are calling it directly from the DOM node (ex: `(x.id)` should just be `$('#doyouneed')`, skipping the `getElementById` altogether.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: you should consider following the [jQuery style guide](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#naming-conventions) and use camel case for your function names.  They are _really_ tedious to read as they are currently written.

Comment: @Derek Thank you for that, I didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add Jquery library

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

After try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=apprentice]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == 'yes')
    {
       $("#yourdiv").slideDown('slow');
    }
    else
    {
       $("#yourdiv").slideUp('slow');
    }
    });

}):
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, I'm here if you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply jquery functions only to **jquery objects**. By selecting with getElementById() you get the DOM object but no the Jquery Object. That is why you use $(this) inside the function to change the css.

I would recommend using:

```
function dropbcitdown() {
    $("#doyouattend").slideDown("slow" function() {
        $(this).css({
        display: "inline";
        })
    })
}
```